# Unwanted wakeup from sleep state

Tags: windows-8, sleep, hibernate

My Windows 8 desktop computer is behaving strangely.

When I leave it in the evening, I set it to standby (or hibernate, doesn't matter). When I come back in the morning, it's on.

I wrote a little PowerShell script to find out more and reset it automatically to Standby:

```
$PowerState = [System.Windows.Forms.PowerState]::Suspend;
$Force = $false;
$DisableWake = $true;

while ($true)
{
    $now = [DateTime]::Now
    $now.ToString("HH:mm:ss dd.MM.yyyy")
    [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::SetSuspendState($PowerState, $Force, $DisableWake);
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 90
}
```

From this I can see that the automatic wakeup is usually once at some time between 3 and 4 o'clock (a.m.). But sometimes it also wakes up twice and at one time it woke up at 06:32, so there isn't a very strong pattern.

I can rule out wake-on-lan, because I physically disconnected the LAN and it still woke up.

There is no WLAN or any other network connection, only keyboard (cable), mouse (bluetooth, but turned off overnight), monitor and joystick. In the BIOS I disabled all "wake-on-xxx" functionality I could find.

It does not wake up when I use "shutdown", only from standby or hibernate.

Any ideas on how I could find out which process/setting/whatever is responsible for this behaviour?

Comment: I've had a similar problem that usually turns out to be vibration triggering a signal from an input device.  A truck going by outside can jostle a mouse or other device enough to register.  You don't indicate whether you have a cat (or a rodent problem)--another common mystery cause.

Comment: I turn off my bluetooth mouse and no key on my keyboard turns the computer on again when in sleep mode. I also have no pets - neither the wanted nor the unwanted variant :-).

Answer (score 0):

IT could be because powershell is not actually setting the computer into sleep mode and instead is just "PRETENDING" it is, and when your computer is set to actually go to sleep (such as after 30 mins of no activity) it turns back on.

Comment: The original problem showed when I set the computer to standby or hibernate through the usual windows menu. The powershell script is just a measure to display the time(s) of wakeup and put it to sleep again automatically. The script works very well.

Comment: Does the issue happen when the script is not running?

Comment: Yes. But when the script isn't running, I just find my computer running in the morning and have no idea at what time it woke up.

Comment: Close all background programs, and disconnect the internet. and then what happens? if the issue was fixed by disconnecting the internet then i would say you have some malitious software on your computer. if the issue fixed by closing back ground programs i would say a program was causing your computer to awaken from its slumber. this is all i have to offer on this, sorry.

Comment: Tried that. I even physically disconnected the LAN. No effect.